# Root-finding in R: command like fzero(f,x0) from MATLAB?

Tags: r, matlab

I am trying to convert some MATLAB code into R. The MATLAB code uses `fzero(f,x0)` to find a root near `x0`, but I am not sure what command in R I could use to do this same thing. I am aware of `uniroot(f, c(a,b))` in R, but that requires searching within the interval between `a` and `b`. Does anyone know if there is something similar to the MATLAB `fzero(f,x0)` in R?

Thanks!

EDIT: I have found `fzero` in R package `pracma`, will try it and report my results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`fzero` from package `pracma` worked for me

Answer (score 0):

I know there is an answer, but it is not the same as an example.

The "fzero" in MatLab (yes, I'm old school) has the feature that you can pass parameters to user-made functions.

For instance, consider the following (from the fzero help in MatLab):

```
 myfun = @(x,c) cos(c*x);  % The parameterized function.
 c = 2;                    % The parameter.
 X = fzero(@(x) myfun(x,c),0.1)
```

(aside) I love the MatLab help documentation.  I consider that a major piece of the value proposition.  It is amazingly learnable, and built for self-teaching.

In this canonical MatLab (or MATLAB) code, you pass the parameter "c" into the "myfun" before you find the nearby root.  A canonical answer in R has to do at least this much.  **How do you get the equivalent of this, in R?**

Of course we need the "pracma" library so that we have the "fzero" function.

```
#library with the fzero function
library(pracma)
```

Here is a declared function.  Note that "t" is not an input.  This makes it a [free variable](http://www.stat.berkeley.edu/~statcur/Workshop2/Presentations/functions.pdf) that does not have local scope.

```
#make a user-defined function
myfun <- function(x) {
     temp <- t - (exp(-0.5*x)/(exp(0)+exp(-0.5*x)));
     return(temp);
}
```

It is totally unfair to duplicate, so I made a new one.

Here is how I could find the "target" given nearby values and the function.

```
#y-values (weights) of interest
target <- c(0.999,0.99,0.95,0.9,0.8,0.75,0.66,0.5,
            0.33,0.25,0.20,0.1,0.05,0.01,0.001)

#initialize for loop
xlist <- numeric()

#loop
for (i in 1:length(target)){
     y <- target[i]
     temp <- fzero(myfun,3)

     xlist[i] <- temp$x
}
```

Then I can plot it and evaluate the performance.

```
#plot it 
plot(x=xlist,
     y=target,
     xlab = "AIC value",
     ylab = "max Akaike weight",
     type="p")

est <- smooth.spline(xlist,target)
x2 <- seq(from=min(xlist),to=max(xlist),length.out=100)
lines(x2,predict(est,x2)$y,col="green")
grid()
```

The resultant plot is this:
[image]

Inspection shows that it does exactly what was needed.